# Thymeleaf : If not working on maps

Tags: thymeleaf

I am trying to create a table in a html template only when a particular map is not empty using Thymeleaf templating engine. However, even when the map is empty, the table gets created with default values.

So, basically I have a `Map<String, List<String>> myMap` which I need to check before creating the html table. I am setting the value correctly in the Context as I can verify by debugging.

```
<div th:if="${not #maps.isEmpty(myMap)}">
    <table cellspacing='0'>
        <tr th:each="instance : ${myMap.instanceMap}">
            <td th:text="${instance.key}">keyvalue</td>
            <td th:text="${instance.value.numOfData}">num</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Also, how do I print the key versus each value for that key ( remember value is a list) in a tabular fashion ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div th:if="not ${myMap.isEmpty()}"> 
    ...
</div>
```

Edit: Forgot the second part of your question, you can also just iterate the list similarly. Examples:

Horizontal display:

```
<table cellspacing='0'>
    <tr th:each="instance : ${myMap}">
        <td th:text="${instance.key}">key</td>
        <td th:each="listObject : ${instance.value}">
                <th:block th:text="${listObject}">List object text</th:block>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Vertical display:

```
<table cellspacing='0'>
    <th:block th:each="instance: ${myMap}">
        <tr th:each="listObject, iterStat : ${instance.value}">
            <td>
                <th:block th:if="${iterStat.index} == 0" th:text="${instance.key}"/>
            </td>
            <td th:text="${listObject}"></td>
        </tr>
    </th:block>
</table>
```

As a reference for the iterStat properties, see: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#keeping-iteration-status

Comment: I am getting the below error : org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 15): Property or field 'instanceMap' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.HashMap' - maybe not public?

Comment: Updated my answer. I was under the impression your map hat some custom wrapper object. just iterate through ${myMap} then.

Comment: Thank you, it is the answer that I am looking for.